# MonoTouch Error when compiling: System.Boolean System.Type::op_Equality(System.Type,System.Type)

Tags: c#, ios, compilation, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch app, when I compile it for the device, I get the following error:

```
Error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Boolean System.Type::op_Equality(System.Type,System.Type) (MT2002)
```

It works fine in the simulator, however occasionally I'll get a `MissingMethodException` with the same type.

I have no 3rd party libraries. All of the code is my own. Any ideas?

**Edit** Here are my 3 projects and all their references.

**Project 1: Mobile.Libraries**

- monotouch
- System
- System.Core
- System.Xml

**Project 2: Mobile.Core**

- Mobile.Libraries
- System
- System.Core
- System.Xml

**Project 3: Mobile.IOS**

- monotouch
- Mobile.Core
- System
- System.Core
- System.Xml

Comment: Are you using a DLL you compiled targeting the Desktop (could be Windows or Mac) at all?  Make sure you are using a MonoTouch Library project for any class libraries you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jonathan.Peppers said this occurs when you use a **compiled** .dll that was built against the full, .NET4, profile.

MonoTouch Base Class Libraries (BCM) provides a superset of the Silverlight profile (2.1) with some 4.0 additions. So adding pre-compiled binaries from another framework can requires some types/methods that are **not** present in MonoTouch BCL.

The solution is to rebuild all your .dll against the BCL assemblies that are shipped with MonoTouch. That will ensure the compiler will only uses symbols that are available.

**Why does it works on the iOS simulator ?**

That's because the JIT is used. Since it's compiled Just In Time you *might* never reach the missing symbols so it *can* work until you hit the missing code (and get a runtime error).

On the other hand when you use the device (or the linker) then all the symbols are loaded (and compiled for AOT). Anything missing will be found *ahead of time* so you get an build-time error like the one above.

Comment: I have no DLL's not compiled in by MT. I compile EVERYTHING in MT. 3 projects, are compiled then each one references the one below.

Comment: Weird, I cannot see how this missing method could be referenced otherwise. Please fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach (you can mark it private) a sample project showing this.

Comment: I Made an edit above. This is my project structure (references). Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes, everything references `mscorlib.dll` (where the missing type is coming from). The is **implied** in MonoDevelop (you don't see it) and it's based on your project type (e.g. if it's not a MonoTouch library / project then it won't be using the right `mscorlib.dll`). IOW if one of your project's options, Build, General, Target framework is **not** set to **Mono for iPhone** you're not linking against the right `mscorlib.dll`

Comment: They are all set to Mono for iPhone. I guess its a bug.

Comment: No sure what was wrong. I cleaned and re-deployed and everything worked. Weird.